# Relative CSS URL values with WebKit (Objective-C API)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, webkit

I want to change the URL's of a background-image property in a HTML document.

```
DOMCSSStyleDeclaration *style = domELement.style;
NSString *imageURL = [style backgroundImage];
```

Now the imageURL looks something like `url(<base URL I've loaded the HTML with>/image.jpg)`. But in the HTML source it's `url(image.jpg)`.
Now I'd like to change the image.jpg to an other image and still keep the relative path. How do I do that? Because when i set something like `url(newImage.jpg)` the rendered output looks like `url(<base URL I've loaded the HTML with>/newImage.jpg)`.

May I change something when getting the HTML?

```
DOMHTMLElement *htmlElement = (DOMHTMLElement*)[document documentElement];
NSString *html = [htmlElement outerHTML];
```

Or is there an other way how I can set a relative URL in a css attribute?

```
[style setBackgroundImage:@"url(newImage.jpg)"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found anything at all. So I did pars it my self with an NSSCanner